# PHP/MYSQL hits counter on dynamic page

Tags: php, mysql

I've been trying to code a php/mysql hit counter on a dynamic page but it just doesn't seem to work. Here's the code so far..

```
while{  
$incre=+1;
$update=$db->prepare("UPDATE hits=hits+1 WHERE id="$sid"");
$data=array($incre,$sid);
$update->execute($data);

$db->prepare("INSERT INTO thread (hits) VALUES (1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE hits=hit+1`");

if($count==null)
    {echo "<p style='text-align:center; clear:both; color:black; font-size:95%;'>Total visits: 0</p>";}
else
    {echo "<p style='text-align:center; clear:both; color:black; font-size:95%;'>Total visits: <b style='color:red;'>".$count."</b></p>";}
}
```

Comment: Sorry but that doesn't work

Comment: What is the "while" statement for? It doesn't have a conditional and it doesn't end. Where is $sid coming from? Is your database connected? What is your table schema? Are either of the sql statements working or are they both failing?

Comment: The while statement gave an error, so I removed it.

Comment: The while statement gave an error, so I removed it. The $sid is the variable assigned to each page. ex: abc.com/page.php?id=1. Yes the database is connected. The table schema is too long so I write the most important column: hits (int). No the sql isn't working, reloading the page doesn't update the number, it remains at zero.

Answer (score 0):

So, there are a lot of problems with your code. You don't set up the sql update statement in a safe way (sql injection). Then you don't call it correctly (you should use named parameters always). Then your insert statement is never called. You also never get the hits count from the db to display. Lots of weird things going on.

```
$update = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO thread (id, hits) VALUES (:id, 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE hits=hits+1");
$update->execute(array(':id' => $sid));

$query = $db->prepare("SELECT hits FROM thread WHERE id=:id");
$query->execute(array(':id' => $sid));
$counter = $query->fetchColumn(0);

echo "<p style='text-align:center; clear:both; color:black; font-size:95%;'>Total visits: <b style='color:red;'>".$counter."</b></p>";
```